# How to delete all but some files with a batch-file?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to delete everything in a folder but some files, let's say `fileA.txt`, `fileB.exe` and `fileC.dll`. How do I process ?

Here is what I tried, but it does not loop over all files and stops at the first, and does not even delete it :

```
for /R %%I in (*.*) do (
    if "%%~nxI" == "fileA.txt" goto cd1
    if "%%~nxI" == "fileB.exe" goto cd1
    if "%%~nxI" == "fileC.dll" goto cd1
    goto cd2

    :cd1
    goto fin

    :cd2
    echo HERE WE MUST DEL THE FILE !
    goto fin

    :fin
    echo Done
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

```
@echo off
call :hide +h
del *.*?
call :hide -h
echo done.
goto :EOF

:hide
for %%a in (
"fileA.txt"
"fileB.exe"
"fileC.dll"
) do attrib %1 "%%~a"
```

Comment: Thanks ! could you quickly explain what you did ?

Comment: I like it, but why not a loop like MC ND's answer ? Is it really a good way to hide and then un-hide files ?

Comment: There are always several ways to solve most problems.  I chose to show you this way. :)

Comment: Nice ! And how would you go recursively in folders and subfolders ?

Comment: Your question doesn't say you want to do it recursively.

Answer (score 3):

Generate the list, remove from it not desired files, delete the rest

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (
  'dir /s /b /a-d * ^| findstr /v /i /e /c:"\\filea.txt" /c:"\\fileb.exe" /c:"\\filec.dll"'
) do del "%%a"
```

For a longer list of exclusions, it is better to create a text file with the list of files to exclude and then use `/g` switch of `findstr` to indicate the strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set exclude=/fileA.txt/fileB.exe/fileC.dll/

for /R %%I in (*.*) do (
    if "!exclude:/%%~nxI/=!" equ "%exclude%" del "%%I"
)
```